# Excel VBA: Calling a ComboBox_Change located in another wb

Tags: vba, excel

When writing a VBA code, I tried to call a Combobox_Change Sub (not Private Sub), which is located in 'Sheet2' of another workbook called 'wb2'.

```
    Call wb2.Sheet2.ComboBox_Change
```

However, the program returns the runtime error 438. Am I missing anything or can someone proovide a fix? Thanks!

> Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: `wb2` is presumably a `Workbook` object, which does not have a `sheet2` property. You'd have to use the sheet tab name: `Call wb2.Sheets("Sheet2").ComboBox_Change` for example.

Comment: Take a look at the following link for use on WithEvents: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx

Comment: @Rory thank you! it works now. I should have tried that before asking the question

Comment: Big Flying Red Flag: you don't want to invoke event handlers explicitly. You want to toggle the combobox state, which has the side-effect of invoking the handler for it. If you want the side-effects without the control state toggle, then have the handler invoke a public procedure, and invoke that same procedure from the other book. Don't make handlers public, write better code instead.

Answer (score 1):

Event handlers do one thing: they *handle events*. That's why they're `Private`: they never need to be explicitly invoked by any other code - they're invoked by their respective event source, period.

- [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36995321/1188513)
- [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/984303/1188513)
- [Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/956255/1188513)

If it's bad practice in every language I could be bothered to find a SO post about this for, then why would it be any different in VBA? Hint: it's not, the reasons why explicitly invoking an event handler is a bad idea, are completely language-agnostic (provided your language has a concept of "event").

Don't make them `Public` and then invoke them explicitly. Instead, have that other code toggle the state of the control, and let the control fire its event - assuming an ActiveX/MSForms control:

```
Dim ctrl As MSForms.ComboBox
Set ctrl = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object
ctrl.Value = Not ctrl.Value
```

If you don't want to toggle the control's state, only to invoke its handler, then pull the handler's implementation out - instead of this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox_Change()
    'do stuff
End Sub
```

Do this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox_Change()
    DoStuff
End Sub
```

```
Public Sub DoStuff()
    'do stuff
End Sub
```

And then invoke `DoStuff` like you would any other macro-in-another-workbook.

Note that the `Call` keyword is completely redundant.

Comment: In this case, `Public DoStuff(SomeUsefulParameter as SomeUsefulType)` to enable broad re-use. For example, your handler or main code could pass the relevant worksheet to the `DoStuff` routine, and you could use this for nay worksheet that is logical to do so.  But I am sure you already thought of that :-)

Comment: @AJD absolutely - there simply wasn't enough meat in the OP to have even the slightest idea what `DoStuff` should be doing though :)